# Error in parameter find

Tags: c++, string

I want to find the position of a word in a string. This is my code but I got an error that says:

```
error: request for member find in buffer1, which is of non-class type std::string [50]
  {aka std::basic_string<char> [50]}.
```

How can I fix it?

```
n = write(SocketFD,"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www-net.cs.umass.edu\r\nUser-Agent: Firefox/3.6.10\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml\r\nAccept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7\r\nKeep-Alive: 115\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n",47);

string buffer1[50];
bzero(buffer1,50);

n=read(SocketFD,buffer1,50);

size_t found = buffer1.find("Lenght");

if(found!=string::npos)
cout<<"posicion"<<found;
```

Comment: Do you really want an array of 50 different strings?

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: You should not use `bzero` on `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

buffer1 is an array of `std::string`. Thus when you call `buffer1.find("Lenght");` You are in fact trying to invoke the method `find` of a `string[]`. There is no such method and so you get the error you see. My guess is that you meant to construct a string of size 50: `string buffer1(50, '\0');`

Please note that this will hardly fix all problems in your code. My guess is that read expects a `char*` and you will not be able to use it with `std::string`.

Answer (score -1):

This can get you started:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  char buf[50];
  int n=read(SocketFD,buffer1,50);
  //might need to add a null terminator
  //especially if it overflows
  string s(buffer);
  size_t found = s.find("brown");
  cout << "position=" << found << endl;
}
```